# Filter dataframe by sum

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['dd','ee','ff'], 'Toy-Figure': [2,3,1], 'Toy-car':[1,2,0], 'Toy-blocks':[5,9,0]})
```

For the above df, I want all Names who have more than 1 toy.
Here's what I have so far, but I can't get the names column. How do I do that ?

```
df_c = df.copy()
df_c[df_c.sum(axis = 1) > 1].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: ```df.loc[df.sum(axis=1)>1,'Name']```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
df[df['Toy-Figure']>1].Name
```

Result:

```
0    dd
1    ee
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll simply add to your solution,

```
df_c = df.copy()
df_c.index = df_c['Name']
df_c[df_c.sum(axis = 1) > 1].sum(axis=1)
```

or

```
df.sum(axis = 1)[df.sum(axis = 1) >1]
```

Comment: Thank you I like this as it gives the count of toys and the name.